# With JFreeCharts, how can I sort the x-axis labels and legend items separately?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a multi-lined chart that contains the following data:

Line 1: Name=B, X-Axis Label=A
Line 2: Name=A, X-Axis Label=C
Line 3: Name=C, X-Axis Label=B

I would like the x-axis labels to show up in the order: A, B, C, and I would like for the legend items to display in that same order. However, depending on the order the data is in when I give it to the chart, one of these may be true but not both.

Is there some class that can be overridden to order x-axis labels and another to order legend items? Or is there an alternative/better solution?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `getLegendItems()` in your Renderer.

Comment: Can i sort the legend items without extending `Renderer`?